# Bootstrap Grid System - How to make next column go to new line

Tags: bootstrap-5

I want to use bootstrap to make new columns which not yet span the twelve available go to a new line. I've already tried offset and margin class but cant get the goal. Th only solution I have for now is to create an empty div with the remaining of the twelve columns. Here an example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form action="" class="row">
  <!-- email control -->
  <div class="mb-3 col-md-3">
    <label for="email" class="form-label">Email Address:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
    <div class="form-text" id="emailHelp">We'll never share your email with anyone.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9"></div>
  <!-- password control -->
  <div class="mb-3 col-md-3">
    <label for="password" class="form-label">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <!-- check control -->
  <div class="mb3 form-check col">
    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="checkMe" class="form-check-input">
    <label for="checkMe" class="form-label">Check me out</label>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what rows are for. Review the [grid docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/#example) to catch the concepts you're missing here.

1. Rows should always be in a container. I've added a fluid one to keep the page full-width.
2. Just use a new row. It's best not to mix elements anyway, so I've moved the row class to divs inside the form.

You didn't really explain your goal, but here are some examples.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <form action="">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- email control -->
      <div class="mb-3 col-sm-3">
        <label for="email" class="form-label">Email Address:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
        <div class="form-text" id="emailHelp">We'll never share your email with anyone.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <!-- password control -->
      <div class="mb-3 col col-sm-6">
        <label for="password" class="form-label">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <!-- check control -->
        <div class="mb3 form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" name="" id="checkMe" class="form-check-input">
          <label for="checkMe" class="form-label">Check me out</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to follow the forms layout as shown in bootstrap docs. What I want is some cases declare how many columns one div will use and in that same div indicate that the leftover space is taken.